# Golang: How can I write a map which is mixed with string and array?

Tags: dictionary, go

I am a beginner of `Go`.
I wrote this code, but an error occurred.
How should I write a map which contains `string` and `[]string` properties?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    prof := make(map[string]map[string]interface{})

    prof["me"] = map[string]string{
        "name":       "John Lennon",
        "email":      "foobar@gmail.com",
        "phone":      "090-0000-0000",
        "occupation": []string{"Programmer", "System Engineer"},
        "language": []string{"Go", "Java", "Python", "PHP", "JavaScript", "SQL"},
        "hobby": []string{"Photography", "Traveling", "Fishing", "Eating"},
    }

    fmt.Println(prof)

}
```

This error is from [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Q0roBI).

```
# _/home/NcWlmE
./prog.go:14: cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type string in map value
./prog.go:15: cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type string in map value
./prog.go:16: cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type string in map value
```

Comment: When using `interface{}`, you have to cast your values back. Also, in your case defining a struct is preferable (Go is not JS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're assigning the wrong kind of map. Try:

```
prof["me"] = map[string]interface{}{
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ instead of string
```

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed my mistake after I posted this. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: 10 minutes later, I will click "check mark". Thank you.

Comment: @yamachan Nothing beats [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!